# swift 3 error using MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making a map

Add the two variables in info.plist "Privacy - Location When Usage Description", "Privacy - Location Always Usage Description"

Error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '

My code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    var manager: CLLocationManager!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        let uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector(("action:")))
        uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0
        map.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)

    }

    func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
        if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began{
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.map)
            let newCoordinate = self.map.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: self.map)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
            annotation.title = "Meu lugar"
            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)



        }
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
        let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(longitude,latitude)
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: false)

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious? `region` seems to be invalid.

Comment: Also there is no need for all of that code; you can just enable user tracking directly on your map view

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to import the CoreLocation framework. I don't think you are getting a valid location object back from the delegate method. Please, import the CoreLocation framework and test it again.

Comment: You don't need to import CoreLocation if you have already imported MapKit. MapKit already imports CoreLocation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` is redundant as you can just call `self.map.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)`

If the user were to pan the map, user tracking will become disabled, so you would need to use this delegate `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didChange mode: MKUserTrackingMode, animated: Bool)` to update the user tracking mode.